# Javascript countdown script from fixed postion

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown script that counts down until a certain day that is specified. I want it to just count down 24 hours every time its loaded but can't seem to get it to happen.

thanks

http://pastebin.com/zQ4ESHuG

Comment: Here's a beautified version of the code http://pastebin.com/vBcF6Ldq

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs){
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000);
tick(); // to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
var secs = timeInSecs;
if (secs>0) {
timeInSecs--;
}
else {
clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
//startTimer(60 * 60 *24 * 5); // and start again if required
}

var days = Math.floor(secs/86400);
secs %= 86400;
var hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
secs %= 3600;
var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
secs %= 60;

var result = ((hours < 10 ) ? "0" : "" ) + hours + ":" + ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins
+ ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
result = days + " Days: " + result;
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Solved it.

Thanks everyone.